# CognitoAuthentication Extension for .NET with Unity (StartWithSrpAuthAsync()) issue

Tags: unity-game-engine, async-await, amazon-cognito, aws-sdk-net

After importing the AWS-SDK for .NET dll's including the AWS.Extension.CognitoAuthentication into Unity 2018.2, I am having a problem with the `StartWithSrpAuthAsync` function taken from `AuthenticateWithSrpAsync` provided by https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/cognitoauthentication-extension-library-developer-preview/

Code from site:

```
public async void AuthenticateWithSrpAsync()
{
    var provider = new AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient(new AnonymousAWSCredentials(),
                                                           FallbackRegionFactory.GetRegionEndpoint());
    CognitoUserPool userPool = new CognitoUserPool("poolID", "clientID", provider);
    CognitoUser user = new CognitoUser("username", "clientID", userPool, provider);

    string password = "userPassword";



    AuthFlowResponse context = await user.StartWithSrpAuthAsync(new InitiateSrpAuthRequest()
    {
        Password = password
    }).ConfigureAwait(false);

}
```

}

I want a button script to take in a username and password from the user and authenticate it with the UserPool I created in Cognito.

Button Script

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using Amazon;
using Amazon.Runtime;
using Amazon.CognitoIdentityProvider;
using Amazon.Extensions.CognitoAuthentication;


public class test : MonoBehaviour {

public string userName;
public string userPassword;
public string clientID;
public string poolID;


public AuthFlowResponse authResponse;
public CognitoUserPool userPool;
public AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient provider;
public CognitoUser user;

void Start()
{

}
public void OnClick()
{
    try
    {
        AuthenticateWithSrpAsync();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.Log(ex);
    }

}

public async void AuthenticateWithSrpAsync()
{
    RegionEndpoint CognitoIdentityRegion = RegionEndpoint.USEast1;
    provider = new AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient(null, CognitoIdentityRegion);
    userPool = new CognitoUserPool(poolID, clientID, provider, null);
    user = new CognitoUser(userName, clientID, userPool, provider);
    string name = user.Username.ToString();
    Debug.Log(name);
    authResponse = await user.StartWithSrpAuthAsync(new InitiateSrpAuthRequest() {

        Password = userPassword

    }).ConfigureAwait(false);
    Debug.Log(user.SessionTokens.IdToken);
    Debug.Log("Success");
}

}
```

The app client does not require a secret key.

App Client

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lk168.jpg

The User status is confirmed/enabled and the email is verified.

User

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CT1X.jpg

What ends up happening is the script runs until it gets to:

```
authResponse = await user.StartWithSrpAuthAsync(new InitiateSrpAuthRequest() {

    Password = userPassword

}).ConfigureAwait(false);
Debug.Log(user.SessionTokens.IdToken);
Debug.Log("Success");
```

And does absolutely nothing afterwards. Neither of the debugs show in the console as well as any Error or warning messages.

Unity Console:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2Pb7.jpg

I have looked through the StackOverflow questions as well as every other resource I could find on google. I have also replicated this in Unity 2017.3

I'm using .NetFramework 4.6

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the checkbox "Enable username-password(non-SRP)...shown in the image in the link https://i.stack.imgur.com/lk168.jpg.

Comment: Unfortunately nothing changed when I did that

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is related to Unity as the same code is working fine at my end. Can you try following:
 _provider = new AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient(new AnonymousAWSCredentials(), );